# Copy selected text from VI in google cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-shell

Trying to copy selected text from a file opened in VI on google cloud shell and paste it in another shell tab. If I select the text in visual mode it wouldn't work. On a local terminal I would use `xclip`, or `shift(+ctrl)` before selecting.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Cloud Shell in the browser and *not* `gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh`, you can simply select text with your mouse/cursor and it will copy it into your clipboard of the browser's OS. In normal or visual mode. See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell#using_the_terminal).

You then paste with middle click, shift+insert, ctrl+shift+v in Linux (assumption based on `xclip` reference).

Comment: It is true that for most applications, if you select text, it is automatically copied to the clipboard.  However, the question was about ```vi```.  The behavior seems different, and selected text isn't automatically copied.  Not sure if the concept of selecting text even applies to ```vi```.

Comment: Yeah, hence the distinction between using a browser (how I assume most people are using Cloud Shell) and `gcloud`.